# Sending an email using servet

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send mail using servlet but there is an exception while trying to send:

```
Exception is :: java.lang.SecurityException
```

Relevant code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");     
  **Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
   new javax.mail.Authenticator()** {  
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
   return new PasswordAuthentication("gmailid","password");//change accordingly
```

Code is giving an exception at the Bold line.Plz give any solution to resolve that problem as soon as possible.
Stacktrace:

```html
 java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied
 at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:333)
 at forget.email2(forget.java:213)
 at forget.doPost(forget.java:101)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There is no bold line. Would you mind being a bit more specific in the "giving an Exception" part? Could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: change  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); to   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Comment: Sourabh Jhunjhunwala : Its not working exception is still there

Comment: Please add stacktrace as mentioned by Jens.

Comment: Stacktrace is getting to lengthy

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the port to `587`.
2. From the error, I am guessing, it's Google's security policy
   avoiding any programmatic access to the specified account.

   Login to the Gmail account from which you need to send the mail and
   open this link:

   ```
   https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
   ```

   On this page, TURN ON `Access for less secure apps` and then try
   again.

Comment: Better if you post complete stack trace (and not only single line `Exception is :: java.lang.SecurityException`)..

Comment: added the stacktrace .

Comment: Can you try with `Session.getInstance()` instead of `Session.getDefaultInstance()` ?

Comment: Yup that exception has been removed but still there is some other exception when it reaches in Transport.send(msg)....Plz suggest something to remove that one.......it is showing that exception  **com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:**

Comment: Full stacktrace please :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76616/discussion-between-roopam-and-pramod-karandikar).